# Check if ONLY connected to WiFi C#

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am currently using [Managed Wifi API](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) to get the SSID of the Wireless network that the device is connected to. Here's my method:

```
public string getSSID() {
    try {
        WlanClient wlan = new WlanClient();
        Collection<String> ConnectedSSIDs = new Collection<string>();

        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlan.Interfaces) {
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
            ConnectedSSIDs.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
        }
        return ConnectedSSIDs[0];
    } catch (Win32Exception) {
        return EMPTY;
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        throw Ex;
    }
}
```

Currently, from this, I can determine whether I am connected to Wifi and Ethernet (because an SSID still exists in that situation) or just Ethernet.

I would like to somehow deduct whether I am JUST connected to Wifi and not Ethernet in addition to that.
I have had a look at:

1. [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx)

Surprisingly, looking at *AdapterType* property of *Win32_NetworkAdapter* (when only connected to Wifi) I am still returned *"Ethernet 802.3"* instead of *"Wireless"* which is what I'd expect.
Unfortunately, I don't think there is a method in *Managed Wifi API* to achieve what I want.

**EDIT**

So I have these 3 constants defined:

```
private const string WIFI_AND_ETHERNET = "WIFI & ETHERNET";
private const string WIFI = "WIFI";
private const string ETHERNET = "ETHERNET";
```

Currently, the method I have shown above can deduct whether the Network connection is `ETHERNET` or `WIFI_AND_ETHERNET`.
It does this by checking if an SSID is available/can be seen. If so, then it will return `WIFI_AND_ETHERNET` but in the absence of one, it will return only `ETHERNET`.

What I need now is for a way to distinguish whether the network connections are via `WIFI` **ONLY** or `WIFI_AND_ETHERNET` together

Comment: Probably this : https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/657473-wmi-wifi-discovery

Comment: @x... neither the question nor the solution work

Comment: You can probably achieve this with ndis using gen_physical_medium. This returns an enum which specifies if it's Bluetooth Ethernet or wireless lab etc. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569621(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this.

```
 var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                      {
                          FileName = "netsh.exe",
                          Arguments = "wlan show interfaces ",
                          UseShellExecute = false,
                          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                          CreateNoWindow = true
                      }
        };
        process.Start();

        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        var lanProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                      {
                          FileName = "netsh.exe",
                          Arguments = "interface show interface name=\"Ethernet\" ",
                          UseShellExecute = false,
                          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                          CreateNoWindow = true
                      }
        };
        lanProcess.Start();
        var lanOutput = lanProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var lanState = lanOutput.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("Connect state"));
        var wlanState = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("State"));
        if (!wlanState.Contains("disconnected")&&lanState.Contains("Disconnected"))

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wi-Fi");
        }
        else if(wlanState.Contains("disconnected") && !lanState.Contains("Disconnected"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ethernet");
        }
        else if (!wlanState.Contains("disconnected") && !lanState.Contains("Disconnected"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wi-Fi & Ethernet");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not connected");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
 var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                      {
                          FileName = "netsh.exe",
                          Arguments = "wlan show interfaces",
                          UseShellExecute = false,
                          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                          CreateNoWindow = true
                      }
        };
        process.Start();

        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var state = output.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains("State"));
        if (!state.Contains("disconnected"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wi-Fi");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ethernet");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: Does not work. Returns when connected to Wifi when connected to BOTH Ethernet and Wifi